# RepositoryItemLookUpEdit not showing display Memeber

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

[image]

My problem in this DevExpress GridView, the `RepositoryItemLookUpEdit` is not showing the result while I find the search exactly in the picture.

This is the code:

```
private void select_product_from_Db_ByOptions_Searche()
    {
        CL_Result = new List<produit>();
        List<int> id_fammille = new List<int>();
        List<int> id_type = new List<int>();

        var res = from p_produit in PMS_Data.myProduit
                  where p_produit.Value.id_famille.HasValue && CL_famille_selected.Contains(p_produit.Value.id_famille.Value) ||
                        p_produit.Value.id_type.HasValue && CL_type_selected.Contains(p_produit.Value.id_type.Value)
                  select p_produit;

        LookUpProduit.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.Standard;
        LookUpProduit.BestFitMode = BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup;
        LookUpProduit.ImmediatePopup = true;

        foreach (var pr in res)
        {
            DataRow dr = cdt_ligne_proposition.NewRow();
            LookUpProduit.PopulateColumns();
            LookUpProduit.AllowFocused = LookUpProduit.AllowFocused;
            dr[0] = LookUpProduit.GetDataSourceRowByDisplayValue(LookUpProduit.DisplayMember);
            dr[1] = pr.Value.pph.ToString();
            dr[2] = pr.Value.ppv.ToString();
            dr[3] = pr.Value.ppv.ToString();
            dr[5] = pr.Value.Id.ToString();
            dr[4] = pr.Value.pph.ToString();
            cdt_ligne_proposition.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        grid_ligne_proposition.DataSource = cdt_ligne_proposition;
        LookUpProduit.DisplayMember = "Produit";
        LookUpProduit.ValueMember = "Id";
    }
```

Comment: It would probably help to edit your post and supply a bit more context. It seems like it would be hard to help you as currently written.

Comment: I need just fill the RepositoryItemLookUpEdit  in the grdiview after do the searche